# How much time and what type of nutrition will make my leg muscles like professional cyclist?

Tags: exercise

Iam 20 years old, male.
Cycling every day only for 20 minutes on MTB bike on little bit hilly terain.I have no specific diet and calories intake plan yet.

Comment: Mainly you need to do 3-6 hours several times a week.

Comment: This feels like a restatement of your previous question https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/71113/how-can-i-reach-upto-olympic-level-competitions

Comment: This is a question that could easily have been answered by using Google. Search for 'professional cyclist training regimen'

Answer (score 11):

To have legs like professional cyclists you need to train like one. With only 20 minutes a day you are not going to make it. You need to find time, many hours per day, most days a week. If you want to get there in the shortest possible time, without injuries, **you need to find yourself a coach**. If your local sport clubs have an amateur cycling section, that's the way to go. Don't worry, your coach will tell you what to eat then.

Comment: I agree with what you say, expect it would be 4-6hrs a day for 6 days a week.

Comment: @abdnChap better now?

Comment: +1. Love it, good job.

Comment: To build muscles you don’t need many hours per day. I think most professional cyclists don’t train for many hours per day either (except in the base training phase where you do a lot of long, low intensity rides).

Comment: @Michael I admit I only know what I observe and read, but [it appears to me they do](https://www.welovecycling.com/wide/2019/02/18/peter-sagan-the-training-schedule-of-a-champion/). Also from another question we know OP only recently started to think about getting to the international levels of skill and fitness, so "base training phase" is indeed what he will do now. He starts from 20 minutes / day, after all.

Comment: @Mołot: My sister is a professional cyclists and most of her weeks are below 20 hours and below 500km. That’s like 3 hours per day on average. And you need a fraction of that just to built the (optical) muscles.